# What is the best way to minimize or prevent/minimize user replies to facebook messenger send message?

Tags: bots, user-experience, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My case: I will use "Send to Messenger" plugin on a web page w/ event info ( concert dates - see example on https://intentwarenow.com/fbm.php , in dev mode).

I will then store the sender id and and the id of info they want to be updated about

Once the date in the event info hits, I will send a notification with messenger.send .

In this case, once I send the info, the user may reply. what is the best to do in this scenario. also, how do I handle a user who wants to "opt-out" if thats what they reply?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- If you want to reply contextually to the user's message, you can use built-in NLP/Wit.ai or any other NLP engine to parse intent and reply with a canned message based on that:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/built-in-nlp

- If you don't want the user to be able to reply, you can set the persistent menu and disable the composer. This will allow you to control the user's response and exclude free text responses:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/persistent-menu

- If the user opts-out, you would cache the PSID on an opt-out list on your backend. Then you would check the recipient.id before doing any message send to and cancel if the user is on the list. If you are using broadcast messages, you can also use custom labels and label predicates to exclude these users:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/